# Calculating cosine similarity in SPARQL

Tags: sparql, embedding, cosine-similarity

I'm looking for a way to calculate [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity) using SPARQL.

Vectors are described in RDF data like this:

```
@prefix rdf:  <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

<http://example.org/london> rdfs:label "London" ;
    rdf:_1 0.011788688 ;
    rdf:_2 0.006153286 ;
    rdf:_3 -0.0034582422 ;
    ...
    rdf:_1536 -0.020006698 .

<http://example.org/united-kingdom> rdfs:label "United Kingdom" ;
    rdf:_1 0.007484864 ;
    rdf:_2 -0.022806747 ;
    rdf:_3 -0.010839927 ;
    ...
    rdf:_1536 0.001866414 .

<http://example.org/united-states> rdfs:label "United States of America" ;
    rdf:_1 0.0070878486 ;
    rdf:_2 -0.02133514 ;
    rdf:_3 -0.000050822895 ;
    ...
    rdf:_1536 -0.012027864 .
```

Answer (score 2):

My query looks like this:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
PREFIX afn: <http://jena.apache.org/ARQ/function#>

SELECT ?embed1 ?embed2 ((SUM(?dot) / (afn:sqrt(SUM(?v1_squared)) * afn:sqrt(SUM(?v2_squared)))) AS ?similarity)
WHERE {
  ?embed1 ?p ?v1 .
  ?embed2 ?p ?v2 .
  FILTER (STRSTARTS(STR(?p), str(rdf:_)))

  BIND((?v1 * ?v1) AS ?v1_squared)
  BIND((?v2 * ?v2) AS ?v2_squared)
  BIND (?v1 * ?v2 AS ?dot) 

}
GROUP BY ?embed1 ?embed2
ORDER BY DESC(?similarity)
```

It requires the `afn:sqrt` function from [Jena's ARQ library](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/query/library-function.html#additional-functions-provided-by-arq) because standard SPARQL 1.1 does not provide an `sqrt` function.

It seems to work, but probably wouldn't perform well on large data:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| embed1                              | embed2                              | similarity           |
====================================================================================================
| <http://example.org/united-kingdom> | <http://example.org/united-kingdom> | 1.0000000000000002e0 |
| <http://example.org/london>         | <http://example.org/london>         | 1.0e0                |
| <http://example.org/united-states>  | <http://example.org/united-states>  | 1.0e0                |
| <http://example.org/united-states>  | <http://example.org/united-kingdom> | 0.8804311835944831e0 |
| <http://example.org/united-kingdom> | <http://example.org/united-states>  | 0.8804311835944831e0 |
| <http://example.org/london>         | <http://example.org/united-kingdom> | 0.8510995877458968e0 |
| <http://example.org/united-kingdom> | <http://example.org/london>         | 0.8510995877458968e0 |
| <http://example.org/london>         | <http://example.org/united-states>  | 0.7855264600385297e0 |
| <http://example.org/united-states>  | <http://example.org/london>         | 0.7855264600385297e0 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```